# What Google Cloud APIs should I open access for authentication, Firebase real-time database service and Speech to text API

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am trying to secure my Android application. It uses authentication provided by Google Firebase, I also store some information using Firebase Real-time database, and finally, the main functionality of the app relies on Speech-to-Text API provided also by Google.

I believe all these, can be restricted to one application (package name and app signature).

I have been playing the classic exclusion experiment, by enabling then disabling one API at a time, I couldn't find the right combination, nor any hint, any restriction yields a complete "UNAUTHORIZED" access.

The only option running now is not to restrict at all.

For what I tried already:

1. Firebase real-time database management API (enabled and disabled)
2. Cloud pub/sub API (I remember I saw this somewhere talking about Speech to text or Firebase but I am not sure!!)
3. Firebase management and Firebase installation APIs

Always with

- Cloud speech-to-text API

[image: credentials, APIs and services page]

Without any restriction at all, all works great, Authentication/database and speech-to-text; The project connects well with the only first App level connection by providing package name and application signature hash.

[image]

Comment: I note that any restriction takes more than 5 minutes for me to retest. It deserves these manual tests, but it is painful also to test the app functionalities (auth, and voice to text service) because of the flow of the application (remove local cache, retry authentication then service...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find solution myself, banal canonical approach:

1. Set no restrictions at all except the first level (installation step) app package name and signature in Firebase.
2. Run your application and try all functionalities as a normal user.
3. Wait for statistics to be gathered and open this tab https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=##PROJECTNAMEHERE##&show=all
4. Set the right APIs to restrict for your Android/Web application.

Example

[image]

5. Wait for more than 5 minutes, then test again. If it does not work come here x)